# RGB gets wrong values

Tags: arduino, led, mosfet, led-strip

I have `Arduino` which output 3 `pwm` signals into the gate of a `irf731` FET transistors.
Their **source** is grounded, and their **drain** is going to the R/G/B of a `led strip`.
The led strip also gets 12v , so it has 4 pins, **12v,R,G,B**(rgb from the drains) .

When i set an RGB value for *red* , i get the first `gate` on `3.3v`, and the others on 0 .

Problem is , the led strip is **ON** but *very low*, and show wrong colours ( trust me, i have checked multiple times that my colours are connected ok to the FETS and Arduino)

It seems that maybe the `FETS` are not working properly with the `3.3v` on their `gate`, could that be the problem? if so, how would you chose another FET or correct this one ?

Comment: Did you look at the datasheet before choosing that part?

Comment: The IRF731 is a terrible choice for this job. It can't be properly driven direct from a Arduino IO pin. Pick a logic level mosfet instead.

Comment: [This](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/152132/level-shift-circuit-mcu-to-mosfet/152134#152134) might be reusable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that maybe the FETS are not working properly with the 3.3v on their gate, could that be the problem? if so, how would you chose another FET or correct this one ?

Yes, this is the issue. You want an n channel mosfet with a **VGS** that is near or less than your control voltage. For a typical Arduino this is 5V or 3.3v. Otherwise the mosfet will not fully open.

Additionally make sure the Arduino ground is tied to the led strip ground.

Comment: You don't want the Vgs near the control voltage, you want it less than the control voltage. The on resistance is usually specified with the Vgs value that gives that resistance.